# Android 11 wifi SSID is unknown in background even when location permissions are granted

Tags: android, android-wifi

I tested this code in Android 11

```
val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder().apply {
    addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
}.build()
        
connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
    
    override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
        super.onAvailable(network)
        val wifiName = getCurrentlyConnectedName() ?: return
        val wifiMac = getCurrentlyConnectedMac() ?: return
        Timber.d("WifiStateManager onAvailable() called with: network = [$wifiName]")
    }

    override fun onLost(network: Network) {
        super.onLost(network)
        Timber.d("WifiStateManager onLost() called with: network = [$network]")
    }
})
```

And noticed a strange behavior. When the app is in the background `wifi ssid` is always `<unknown>` (**please note that Location permission is granted 100%**). When the app is in the foreground everything is OK and I get the correct `wifi ssid`.

Why this is happening? How to get wifi SSID even when the app is in the background on Android 11?

Comment: I have the same problem, no answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange this hasn't been answer sooner.

Location permission has now a special case for background access on Android 11+. One app can be granted access to location permission, but only in foreground. Background location permission requires a special request on Play Console to be published and get the corresponding permission:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
```

Starts with targeting API 29 I believe which is mandatory already on Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct behavior on **Android 10+(API 29 and higher)**, declaring `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions is not enough.

**1. For foreground location:**

You also need to declare a `foregroundServiceType` of `location` in your Service to use foreground location.

```
<service
    android:name="MyNavigationService"
    android:foregroundServiceType="location" ... >
    <!-- Any inner elements would go here. -->
</service>
```

Or if your code running in the Activity, the activity should be visible to the user.

**2. For background location:**

As [3c71](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807452/3c71) said, you should declare the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission in your app's manifest in order to request background location access at runtime.

Due to the Google Play [location policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9799150), it may reject apps which require background location permission. So, I think the foreground location should be a better choice.

**Official document:** https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions